# iPhone text messages

Tags: iphone, text, messages

I do not want my new iPhone to open text messages automatically when I tap the icon because of this recent scam thing with "you've won a prize". I've gotten that message 3 times so far, and I have to wait until someone sends me another message to keep it from opening automatically.  Last night, I asked someone to send a message, they sent it, and I was able to go into text messaging & delete the "prize" message without opening it.  It popped back up within a short time, so I would like to be able to select text message without my iPhone automatically opening the message if there is only one new one.

Comment: Im not sure what the "prize" thing you mention is all about, but if it's just a text message, and not an email, then there should be no problem with just reading and deleting it, there is nothing it can do just by being viewed.

Answer (score 5):

I had a google, and [found this](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/05/08/spam-scams-sms/) for background reading.

Unlike email, which has the potential to be abused without your consent merely by opening a message, there is no risk attached to simply viewing such messages provided they are received over the SMS network.  They may contain links that you do not want to visit, but they cannot visit those links for you without your direct consent (and indeed action to click it).  So if you receive such messages, simply delete them.  For peace of mind, don't delete the message directly (there is a small change a swipe could go wrong and leave you clicking the link by accident) just drop back to the recipient list, and delete the conversation.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't know if there might be a problem just by opening it.  Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit the lock button twice, the slider on the unlock screen won't go directly to the app.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid I have to disagree. Here in Argentina those "scam" SMS are risky. The simple act of opening one of those messages allows the company to charge you a monthly fee just for receiving more SMS (scams) daily. I know it's an abuse from the phone company allowing this, but it's happening here. Consumers are not protected in Argentina, that's why they worked around this Iphone flaw.

Comment: I don't think this is correct; there is no technical way, simply by reading the SMS, that anyone can be notified you have read it. Is there any concrete evidence that this has happened?